# Adding a menu item to a FlowDocumentReader ContextMenu

Tags: wpf, contextmenu, flowdocumentreader

The FlowDocumentReader has two menu items in its ContextMenu, Copy and Select All.  I'd like to add an additional MenuItem to it and have tried this:

```
    private void FlowDocumentReader_ContextMenuOpening(object sender, ContextMenuEventArgs e)
    {
        flowDocumentReader.ContextMenu.Items.Clear();
        MenuItem menuItem = new MenuItem();
        menuItem.Header = "Test";
        flowDocumentReader.ContextMenu.Items.Add(menuItem);
    }
```

additionally I've tried this:

```
    private void FlowDocumentReader_ContextMenuOpening(object sender, ContextMenuEventArgs e)
    {
        MenuItem menuItem = new MenuItem();
        menuItem.Header = "Test";
        flowDocumentReader.ContextMenu.Items.Add(menuItem);
    }
```

where I don't clear the items in the context menu and attempt to append it.  Neither of these work.

I can create my own menu like so:

```
    private void FlowDocumentReader_ContextMenuOpening(object sender, ContextMenuEventArgs e)
    {
        MenuItem menuItem = new MenuItem();
        menuItem.Header = "Test";
        flowDocumentReader.ContextMenu.Items.Add(menuItem);
        e.Handled = true;
        ContextMenu menu = new ContextMenu();
        MenuItem a = new MenuItem();
        a.Header = "A";
        menu.Items.Add(a);
        MenuItem b = new MenuItem();
        b.Header = "B";
        menu.Items.Add(b);
        flowDocumentReader.ContextMenu.Items.Clear();
        flowDocumentReader.ContextMenu = menu;
        menu.IsOpen = true;
    }
```

And that'll show up, but what I'd like to have is the Copy and Select All menu items as well as A and B.

Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I arrived at was to simply recreate those MenuItems on the new Menu and cancel the display of the built-in ContextMenu that is normally displayed.  There are a number of built-in [ApplicationCommands](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms616816.aspx) which can be incorporated into your own custom ContextMenu and the implementation of this is quite straightforward.

Assume that I've got a ContextMenu created from some method, GetContextMenu(), the following event handler rejects the opening of the built-in ContextMenu and substitutes the one returned from the call to GetContextMenu() and adds in the Copy command (Select All is similar).

```
private void flowDocumentReader_ContextMenuOpening(object sender, ContextMenuEventArgs e)
{
   e.Handled = true;  // keeps the built-in one from opening
   ContextMenu myMenu = GetContextMenu();
   MenuItem copyMenuItem = new MenuItem();
   copyMenuItem.Command = ApplicationCommand.Copy;
   copyMenuItem.CommandTarget = myFlowDocument;
   myMenu.Items.Add(copyMenuItem);
   ShowMenu(myMenu);
}

private void ShowMenu(ContextMenu menu)
{
   menu.Placement = PlacementMode.MousePoint;
   menu.PlacementRectangle = new Rect(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
   menu.IsOpen = true;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You could also do this in the xaml for the **FlowDocument**:

```
<FlowDocument.ContextMenu>
     <ContextMenu>
          <MenuItem Header="{Resx Copy}" Command="Copy"/>
          <MenuItem Header="{Resx SelectAll}" Command="SelectAll"/>
          <MenuItem Header="{Resx CustomCommand}" Command="{Binding CustomCommand}"/>
     </ContextMenu>
</FlowDocument.ContextMenu>
```

(Headers conveniently localized thanks to Grant Frisken's [Resx Extension](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/35159/WPF-Localization-Using-RESX-Files)) :)

If this needs to be applied to many FlowDocuments, you could also define it in a default style somewhere:

```
<Style TargetType="FlowDocument">
    <Setter Property="ContextMenu">
         <Setter.Value>
              <ContextMenu>
                  <MenuItem Header="{Resx Copy}" Command="Copy"/>
                  <MenuItem Header="{Resx SelectAll}" Command="SelectAll"/>
                  <MenuItem Header="{Resx CustomCommand}" Command="{Binding CustomCommand}"/>
              </ContextMenu>
         </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```